# как методом __str__ задать количество отображаемых символов объекта?

Tags: python, django, ооп, строки

Мне необходимо в данном классе, при выводе на страницу, оставить только первые 15 символов текста. Вот что я написал на данный момент, но этот метод не работает:

```
PRE_TEXT_LEN: int = 15


class Post(models.Model):
    """Класс постов с сообщениями."""
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name='Дата публикации'
    )
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
        verbose_name='Группа'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='posts',
        verbose_name='Автор'
    )

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{ self.text[:PRE_TEXT_LEN] }'
```

необходимо использовать метод `__str__`. Если кто знает как правильно можно это сделать?

```
def index(request):
    """Главная страница."""
    header = 'Это главная страница проекта Yatube'
    title = 'Последние обновления на сайте'
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:ORDER_OBJECTS]
    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'title': title,
        'header': header,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<main> 
  <!-- класс py-5 создает отступы сверху и снизу блока -->
  <div class="container py-5">     
    <h1>{{ header }}</h1>
    <article>
    {% for post in posts %}
      <ul>
        <li>
          Автор: {{ post.author.get_full_name }}
        </li>
        <li>
          Дата публикации: {{ post.pub_date|date:"d E Y" }}
        </li>
      </ul>      
      <p>
        {{ post.text }}
      </p>
    {% if post.group %}   
      <a href="{% url 'posts:group_list' post.group.slug %}">все записи группы</a>
    {% endif %} 
      {% if not forloop.last %}<hr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </article>
    <!-- под последним постом нет линии -->
  </div>  
</main>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Вопрос то у вас в чём? Если ваш код не работает, нужно написать, что именно происходит, какие ошибки и т.д.

Comment: вопрос в том как правильно написать метод __str__. Ошибок никаких нет, как и изменений. в том-то и дело

Comment: я не вижу никаких ошибок. разве что, это возвращаемое значение незачем оборачивать в f-строку

Comment: «этот метод не работает» — как вы это определили? Где и почему вы ожидаете увидеть какие-то изменения?

Comment: @andreymal, потому что не выводится ожидаемый результат, а именно - первые 15 символов каждого поста

Comment: @AkhmedGandaev не выводится где? Почему вы решили, что место, в котором «не выводится», вообще хоть как-то использует \_\_str\_\_?

Comment: @andreymal, не выводится на странице локального сервера. использует через view-функцию

Comment: А что вместо этого выводится?

Comment: выводится пост целиком

Comment: @AkhmedGandaev продолжаем дальше: почему вы решили, что эта ваша «view-функция» вообще хоть как-то использует \_\_str\_\_?

Comment: @andreymal, а вот это интересный вопрос, на который нет ответа
добавил в вопрос еще индекс

как передать сюда метод?

Comment: @AkhmedGandaev покажите posts/index.html видимо

Comment: Методом гадания на кофейной гуще предположу, что в шаблоне у вас указано брать текст из поля text (т.е. весь текст целиком), а не просто пост.

Comment: Ну да, замените `{{ post.text }}` на просто `{{ post }}` наверное

Comment: нет. не помогло(

Comment: А если прям в лоб `{{ str(post) }}`? )

Comment: @CrazyElf Django-шаблонизатор не умеет в скобочки и вызовы функций (а вообще мне моя кофейная гуща подсказывает, что просто кэш почистить надо, но чёт не уверен)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо! Это было правильное решение, просто надо было кэш почистить)